# django - multiple permissions or clause

Tags: python, django

If I have a view with permissions like the following:

```
permission_classes_by_action = {'list': [CanListUser, IsSupport, IsServiceDesk]
```

How could I structure it where if `IsSupport` OR `IsServiceDesk` returns True then access is granted?

I'm guessing I need to wrap them into the `CanListUser` permission?

```
class CanListUser(permissions.BasePermissions):
    if True in [IsSupport, IsServiceDesk]:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Or would it be like this?

```
class CanListUser(permissions.BasePermissions):
    if [IsSupport, IsServiceDesk]:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Comment: first one and also you don't need else block.

Comment: @AvinashRaj I just tried and this doesn't work.  It won't read from the list.

Comment: hope both are false.. try `if IsSupport or IsServiceDesk:`

Comment: I apologize @AvinashRaj turns out I was breaking my app elsewhere you were correct it's the first assumption.  You can post it as an answer and I'll accept it.